# How to draw parts of a line dotted with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles, line

I want to create a straight line between two nodes in a `tikzpicture` interrupted in the middle by a dotted portion. This should work whatever the orientation of the line.

Here is an expected output:

[image]

The best would be to have a line style defined for this instead of each time using `clip` to remove the straight line and then tweak a dotted one to fit the hole. A minimal code for the solution would look like

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    middle dotted line/.style={
        thick, 
        % YOUR HELP HERE
    }
}% end of tikzset


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) at (0, 3) {};
    \node (B) at (5, 3) {};
    \node (C) at (0, 2) {};
    \node (D) at (5, 0) {};
    \draw[middle dotted line] (A) -- (B);
    \draw[middle dotted line] (C) -- (D);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I take it \draw (A) -- (B) node[midpoint, fill=white, sloped]{$\cdots$};` won't do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Inspired by [Mark Wibrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/204501/1952)

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\tikzset{%
  middle dotted line/.style={
    decoration={show path construction, 
      lineto code={
          \draw[#1] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) --($(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)!.3333!(\tikzinputsegmentlast)$);,
          \draw[dotted,#1] ($(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)!.3333!(\tikzinputsegmentlast)$)--($(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)!.6666!(\tikzinputsegmentlast)$);,
          \draw[#1] ($(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)!.6666!(\tikzinputsegmentlast)$)--(\tikzinputsegmentlast);,
      }
    },
    decorate
  },
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[middle dotted line] (0,0)--(4,1);
\draw[middle dotted line={line width=1.5pt}] (1,1)--(3,4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Using the [`spath3`](https://github.com/loopspace/spath3) library (at time of writing, needs the development version from github).

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/639726/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spath3}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[spath/save=path,ultra thick, red] (0,0) -- +(3,0);
\draw[spath/split at keep start={path}{1/3},spath/use=path];
\draw[spath/split at keep end={path}{2/3},spath/use=path];
\draw[spath/split at keep middle={path}{1/3}{2/3},spath/use=path,dotted];

\draw[spath/save=path,ultra thick, red] (0,-1) .. controls +(6,-1) and +(-6,-1) .. +(3,0);
\draw[spath/split at keep start={path}{1/3},spath/use=path];
\draw[spath/split at keep end={path}{2/3},spath/use=path];
\draw[spath/split at keep middle={path}{1/3}{2/3},spath/use=path,dotted];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It works by splitting the path into three components and then rendering each component with a different style.  As Henri mentions in the comments, to have a genuine solid and dotted line requires (at least) two draw commands - one for each style.  I use one for each segment since combining the first and last segments would actually lead to slightly more complicated code.

As it uses the `spath3` library, it works on arbitrary paths.

Here's the result:

[image: solid and dotted lines]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, because it works on arbitrarily curved paths. The currently accepted answer only works on straight paths.

Comment: It's a forlorn hope, I know, but it would be useful if the downvoter explained what they felt was bad about this answer.  I try to be helpful on this site and when I miss the mark then the only way I'll improve is if I know what went wrong.

Comment: Maybe use a lighter color instead of red. I only saw the black line and dots at second glance ...

Comment: @JasperHabicht good suggestion - next time I'm on a suitable machine I'll hange it to a lighter shade

Answer (score 5):

Without guru's tricks try this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (0,0) coordinate (A) (3,5) coordinate (B);
    \path (A)--(B) node [inner sep=0pt,pos=.333] (C) {};
    \path (A)--(B) node [inner sep=0pt,pos=.666] (D) {};
    \draw (A)--(C);
    \draw (D)--(B);
    \draw[dotted] (C)--(D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: If you use the `calc` library then you can do your coordinate calculations all in one go without creating extra nodes.  (It feels sufficiently close to this answer that I don't want to post a separate answer just for that, but you could add an example using `calc`)

Comment: @AndrewStacey Thanks for your suggestion. But I post my answer just for its simplicity, without the help of others packages or libraries. I know that I can calculate the coordinates of my intermediates points C(1,5/3) and D(2,10/3): the parameter pos of Tikz make the job!

Comment: Fair enough.  I've added a separate `calc` answer then as I think it's a useful example to show how the `calc` library can shorten the code.

Comment: an code-cleaning suggestion: using `coordinate` is more suitable than `node`. `\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0) coordinate (A) --(3,5) coordinate (B)
coordinate[pos=1/3] (C) coordinate[pos=2/3] (D);
\draw (A)--(C) (D)--(B);
\draw[dotted] (C)--(D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 5):

With the `subpath` function and time along a path, Asymptote handles this task very easy, for any curve.

[image]

```
unitsize(1cm);

// for curvy curves
path p=(0,-1) .. controls (0,-1)+(6,-1) and (3,-1)+(-6,-1) .. (3,-1);
real t1=.4,t2=.6;   // times on path
path q1=subpath(p,0,t1);
path q2=subpath(p,t1,t2);
path q3=subpath(p,t2,1);
draw(q1^^q3,magenta);
draw(q2,magenta+dotted);

// of course it works for straight lines
path pline=(0,0)--(3,1);
real s1=.3,s2=.7;   // times on path

path q1line=subpath(pline,0,s1);
path q2line=subpath(pline,s1,s2);
path q3line=subpath(pline,s2,1);
draw(q1line^^q3line,blue);
draw(q2line,blue+dotted);

shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible));
```

Comment: It's great seeing how other technologies approach problems.  Now all we need is a `pstricks` solution to complete the set!

Answer (score 3):

A minor variation of Raffaele Santoro's answer using the `calc` library to shorten the code.  It produces the same output.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (0,0) coordinate (A) (3,5) coordinate (B);
    \draw (A)--($(A)!1/3!(B)$) ($(A)!2/3!(B)$) -- (B);
    \draw[dotted] ($(A)!1/3!(B)$) -- ($(A)!2/3!(B)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The code can be shortened even more when this is needed more than once: `\tikzset{middle dotted line/.style args={#1 and #2}{to path={--($(\tikztostart)!#1!(\tikztotarget)$) coordinate(@s) ($(\tikztostart)!#2!(\tikztotarget)$) coordinate(@e) --(\tikztotarget) (@s)edge[line to,dotted](@e)}}}` and then use it with `\draw (A) to[middle dotted line=1/3 and 2/3] (B);`.

Answer (score 2):

A solution using decorations which also works with curved paths:

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

\pgfdeclaremetadecoration{middle part dotted}{initial}{
    \state{initial}[width={\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength/3}, next state=medial]{
        \decoration{curveto}
        \afterdecoration{
            \pgfusepath{stroke}
        }
    }
    \state{medial}[width={\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength/3}, next state=final]{
        \beforedecoration{
            \pgfsetdash{{\pgflinewidth}{2pt}}{0pt}
        }
        \decoration{curveto}
        \afterdecoration{
            \pgfusepath{stroke}
        }
    }
    \state{final}{
        \beforedecoration{
            \pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
        }
        \decoration{curveto}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[decorate, decoration={middle part dotted}] (0,0) -- +(3,0);

\draw[decorate, decoration={middle part dotted}] (0,-1) .. controls +(6,-1) and +(-6,-1) .. +(3,0);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This needs a bit more math to make the pattern balanced/symmetrical …

Idea: Use the `decorations` library to get the length of the path and create a custom dash pattern that fits.

More work is needed for any dash pattern (that has more than one `on` and one `off` part) or any combination of dash patterns. Besides fractions of the path lengths one could even use absolute lengths (say, if only 1cm should be dotted and not 30% of the middle).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\makeatletter
\def\pgfutil@Repeat#1#2{#2\ifnum#1>0
  \expandafter\pgfutil@firstofone\else\expandafter\pgfutil@gobble\fi
  {\expandafter\pgfutil@Repeat\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1-1\relax}{#2}}}
\tikzset{
  dash between/.code args={#1 and #2}{%
    \tikz@addoption{%
      \pgfgetpath\currentpath
      \pgfprocessround{\currentpath}{\currentpath}%
      \pgf@decorate@parsesoftpath{\currentpath}{\currentpath}%
      \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\firstpart{(#1)*\pgf@decorate@totalpathlength}%
      \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\secondpart{(#2-(#1))*\pgf@decorate@totalpathlength}%
      \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\thirdpart{(1-(#2))*\pgf@decorate@totalpathlength}%
      \edef\thirdpart{{\thirdpart}{0pt}}%
      \edef\firstpart{{\firstpart}{0pt}}%
      \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\secondpartlength{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dash between on}
                                            +(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dash between off})}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\repetitions{\secondpart/\secondpartlength}%
      \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\secondexpand{\secondpart/\repetitions-\secondpartlength}%
      \edef\secondexpand{\the\dimexpr\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dash between off}+\secondexpand\relax}%
      \edef\secondpart{%
        \pgfutil@Repeat{\the\numexpr\repetitions-1\relax}%
          {{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dash between on}}{\secondexpand}}%
      }%
      \edef\tikz@temp{\firstpart\secondpart\thirdpart}%
      \expandafter\pgfsetdash\expandafter{\tikz@temp}{+0pt}%
    }
  }
}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  dash between style/.is choice,
  dash between style/dotted/.style        ={dash between on=\pgflinewidth,dash between off=2pt},
  dash between style/densely dotted/.style={dash between on=\pgflinewidth,dash between off=1pt},
  dash between style/loosely dotted/.style={dash between on=\pgflinewidth,dash between off=4pt},
  dash between style/dashed/.style        ={dash between on=3pt,dash between off=2pt},
  dash between style/loosely dashed/.style={dash between on=3pt,dash between off=6pt},
  dash between style/densely dashed/.style={dash between on=3pt,dash between off=2pt},
  dash between style/no/.style={dash between on=0pt, dash between off=1pt},% dirty
  dash between on/.initial=\pgflinewidth,
  dash between off/.initial=2pt,
  %
  middle dotted line/.style={
    thick,
    dash between=.35 and .65}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (0, 3)
     coordinate (B) at (5, 3)
     coordinate (C) at (0, 2)
     coordinate (D) at (5, 0);
    \draw[middle dotted line] (A) -- (B);
    \draw[middle dotted line] (C) -- (D);
    \draw[
      ultra thick,
      dash between=1/3 and 2/3,
      dash between style=dotted,
    ] (0,-1) .. controls +(6,-1) and +(-6,-1) .. +(3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I could see [`dash pattern={.5:solid, 1:dashed}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/659637/16595).

Answer (score 2):

Yet an other solution- I just add the three parts with a `postaction` decoration:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing} 
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
middle part dotted/.style={
draw=none,
postaction={draw, decoration={curveto, post=moveto, post length=2/3*\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength}, decorate},
postaction={draw, dotted, decoration={curveto, pre=moveto, pre length=1/3*\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength, post=moveto, post length=1/3*\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength}, decorate},
postaction={draw, decoration={curveto, pre=moveto, pre length=2/3*\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength}, decorate},
},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[middle part dotted] (0,0) -- +(3,0);
\draw[middle part dotted] (0,-1) .. controls +(6,-1) and +(-6,-1) .. +(3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Line and curve with middle part dotted]